# How to control opacity of Kubuntu default panel?

Tags: kubuntu, panel, dock, plasma-5, transparency

I use Kubuntu 18.04 with all recent updates.

My issue is that Kubuntu default panel is always transparent (the one on the screen bottom, with task manager, system tray and application launcher).

This is very uncomfortable, because it is configured to auto hide, and when it appears in front of a window with white background, nothing can be read on it.

Example of that panel, appearing in front of a window with dark background:

[image]

As you can see, white letters of the background window clash with white letters of items of the task manager, and the white launcher icon on the left (K with tooth-wheel) is almost invisible.

And here is how that panel looks in front of Opera, showing a page with white background:

[image]

I want to turn that transparency off.

I've tried turning off Translucency effects in System settings, also tried to turn them on and set 100% opacity, but nothing helps.

What temporary helps is to recreate that panel:  remove panel and add a new one (Right click on desktop -> Add panel -> Kubuntu default panel).

But this recreated panel becomes translucent again after system reboot.

These screenshots are made with "Kubuntu" default theme.
Changing Desktop theme doesn't help too.

UPD: I've also tried setting window rules for the dock to force 100% opacity, similar to what was suggested in comments by @Justice for Monica - it also haven't helped.

UPD2: Looks like this transparency is somehow connected to the system tray. Yesterday I've recreated the panel and set forced transparency 90% and turned my PC off.
Today after system boot, the panel was almost completely opaque.
And that buggy transparency has returned after I've configured Krusader to minimize into system tray and restored it.

UPD3: Buggy transparency gets back if I edit system tray settings and switch entries from "Auto" to "Shown".

Comment: I have installed themes from KDE store, but this effect appears with "Kubuntu" theme

Comment: Good point. I use Breeze or Breeze Dark.

Comment: Switched to Breeze Dark right now - the same effect.

Comment: Can you please check the contents of `~/.config/kwinrulesrc` for any entries with something like `opacityactive=n` and `opacityactiverule=2` and `opacityinactive=n` and 
`opacityinactiverule=2` where `n` could a value between 0 and 100.
? I just managed to make my panel (which is autohide just like yours) have 50% opacity. It's possible that when you installed some theme, it changed your `~/.config/kwinrulesrc` causing all themes to be somewhat transparent. If that's the case, we can undo that.

Comment: And please avoid editing the kwinsrulesrc file directly.

Comment: Open System Settings > Window Management > Window Rules and delete the rule that corresponds to the relevant section in `~/.config/kwinrulesrc`. Click Apply. Log out and log back in. That should fix things, I hope!

Comment: This file doesn't have 'opacity'.
`grep opacity ~/.config/kwinrulesrc`  (empty output)